# Two curious related sums on $\gamma$ and $\ln2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, euler-mascheroni-constant

Given these two curious formulas:

How may you show that?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)\zeta(2n+1)}{2^{2n+1}}\left[2n\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\right)-\frac{(2n)^2+1}{(2n)^2-1}\right]=\gamma\tag1$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)\zeta(2n+1)}{2^{2n+1}}\left[-2n\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\right)+\frac{6n+1}{2n-1}\right]=\ln2\tag2$$

$\gamma=0.577216...; Euler-constant$

Any good hints.

Comment: This both lacks context and is too broad.